# Создание события в журнале Windows системы с Linux машины python

Tags: python, linux, windows

Здравствуйте! Возникла необходимость создавать событие в Event Loge Windows машины удаленно с Linux машины. Возможно ли это с помощью python-а? Если возможно, то какие библиотеки использовать, может есть готовые примеры для образца? Спасибо!

Comment: Если с линукса, я бы использовал SNMP TRAPы для отправки сообщений виндам, а на винде поднял (включил) SNMP и логирование.

Answer (score 1):

С python не подскажу, а вот в консоли событие можно создать так:

```
~/scripts/winexe -U DOMEN/USER%PASSWORD //COMPUTER 'EVENTCREATE /T INFORMATION /ID 1000 /L APPLICATION /D "TEST EVENT"' | iconv -f CP866
```

Пакет `winexe` можно скачать с [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe) (.tar.gz) или с [Яндекс.Диска](https://yadi.sk/d/BdNMkSM6jAzA6) (второй вариант быстрее).

Параметры `EVENTCREATE` можно посмотреть в терминале Windows, набрав команду `eventcreate /?`

```
EVENTCREATE [/S <система> [/U <пользователь> [/P <пароль>]]] /ID <код_события> [/L <журнал>] [/SO <источник>] /T <тип> /D <описание>
Параметры:
  /S <система>                 Подключаемый удаленный компьютер.
  /U [<домен>\]<пользователь>  Пользовательский контекст, в котором должна выполняться эта команда.
  /P <пароль>                  Пароль для этого пользовательского контекста.
  /L <журнал>                  Журнал, в котором следует создать событие.
  /T <тип>                     Тип создаваемого события. Допустимые типы: SUCCESS, ERROR, WARNING, INFORMATION.
  /SO <источник>               Источник для этого события (если не указан, по умолчанию используется "eventcreate"). Допустимым источником является любая строка, представляющая приложение или компонент, создающий это событие.
  /ID <код_события>            Код события для этого события. Допустимым кодом события является любое число в диапазоне от 1 до 1000.
  /D <описание>                Описание для создаваемого события.

Примеры использования:
EVENTCREATE /T INFORMATION /ID 1000 /L APPLICATION /D "Пример создания события в журнале приложений" - запись с типом "Информация", идентификатором 1000 в журнал приложений Windows.
EVENTCREATE /T ERROR /ID 999 /L SYSTEM /SO "Proxy Server" /D "Отключение доступа к Прокси серверу" - запись информации в журнал системы Windows - запись с источником "Proxy Server", уровнем "Ошибка" и кодом события 999 . Поля, содержащие пробелы, должны заключаться в двойные кавычки.
EVENTCREATE /S comp1 /U admuser /P admpassword /ID 1 /T ERROR /L SYSTEM /D "Ошибка доступа пользователя из-за неправильных учетных данных" - запись в системный журнал на удаленном компьютере с именем comp1
EVENTCREATE /S 192.168.1.1 /U admuser /P admpassword /ID 1 /T ERROR /L SYSTEM /D "Ошибка доступа пользователя из-за неправильных учетных данных" - запись в системный журнал на удаленном компьютере с IP адресом 192.168.1.1 
Команду EVENTCREATE иногда имеет смысл использовать в командных файлах, когда, например, возникает необходимость зафиксировать отработку определенных этапов в задачах, выполняемых планировщиком. 
  /?                           Вывод справки по использованию.
```